# Пересоздается активити при нажатии на Back button в toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Пересоздается предыдущее активити при нажатии на Back button в toolbar? Как это убрать?

```
 <activity
        android:name="rasul.android.sfera.ui.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="rasul.android.sfera.ui.PostActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Покажите немного кода, манифеста...

Comment: Добавил код манифеста

Comment: Вроде ничего страшного тут не видно. Либо вы сами пересоздаёте (надо код смотреть), либо как-то не так завершаете текущую, либо вы что-то не то понимаете под пересозданием. Попробуйте подробнее проблему описать.

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартное поведение системы при использовании up-navigation. 
Чтобы активити не пересоздавалось, попробуйте поставить флаг `android:launchMode="singleTop"` у `MainActivity` в манифесте.

Либо второй вариант, убрать `android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity"` у `PostActivity` и определить поведение при нажатии стрелки назад вручную.